# Making line thickness based on the sum of overlapping lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, cartography, overlapping-features

In QGIS 3.22.2 I have used the ORS distribution calculation tool to work out the number of vehicles that go from one origin to multiple destinations. I am trying to represent this number as a line width of the sum of the number of persons expected to travel along the route.

I have used the graduated symbology with the set width but this only shows the largest line not the sum of the overlapping lines.

I there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: i.e. `sum("NumsPerson", group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))` (and also maybe brake lines before into linestrings)

Comment: `Dissolve` your route network. Then use `split lines at points` with your dissolve network and either manually set points, or the extracted vertices. Make sure every line segment has a unique ID. `Join attributes by location` from your original data to your split lines, while allowing one-to-many joins. Finally run the following through the field calculator: `sum("passenger numbers",group_by:="ID of the line segments")`. This sums up the number of passengers along the current line segment. Different from the linked question this works with partly overlapping features.

Comment: After a breif experiment this morning, i have to tip my hat to Erik, it looks like your idea worked perfectly. Thank you!!!